# Detect circle with perfect circumference of circle

Tags: python, opencv

Need to detect the circle with perfect circumference with Python, also wanted to create rule for future purpose

**Rule(s)**

- without any overlapping circumference.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97V1X.jpg) [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKTXe.png)

following code tried for detection of Circle but the [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POFa7.jpg) is taking all the Circle where overlapping on circumference. follow is the code for the reference.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="Path to Image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

image = cv.imread(args['image'])
output = image.copy()
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_gray = cv.Canny(img_gray,100,200)
img_gray = cv.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (21,21), cv.BORDER_DEFAULT)

circles = cv.HoughCircles(img_gray, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, \
    param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)

dectected_circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles)) #round(circles[0:]).astype("int")

for (x, y, r) in dectected_circles[0, : ]:
    cv.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    cv.circle(output, (x, y), 2, (0, 128, 255), 3)

cv.imwrite('result.jpg',output)
```

Comment: Hi, so your only problem are the circles on the right where you only want one of them?

Comment: Please do not spam tags, this is not related to tensorflow

Comment: @H4kor, Yes, I would like to detect the circles which are dosen't have overlaping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the documentation of HoughCircle, there is a parameter called minDist that specifies the minimum distance between detected circles. If you know the diameter of the circles to be detected, either by some prior knowledge or by doing a first pass using HoughCircles, you can then do a second pass with minDist set appropriately. This should give you only one detection for the overlapping circles.

On the other hand, if the circles on the right should not be detcetd at all, then I would simply loop through all detections and discard those whose distance is smaller that the sum of the two radii.

Best regards

Andreas